# Using 2 internet connections (cable and mobile)

Tags: windows, internet, internet-connection, windows-server-2012

Is there any possibility to use as default my cable internet and mobile if my cable will go down but I want to switch to mobile internet AUTOMATICALLY. OS: Windows 7/8/2012

Comment: Are you looking for your computer to do this, or your entire LAN to do this?  If LAN, you'll need a router with dual WAN ports and failover

Comment: its for my computer, not a router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think so... open Network and Sharing Center > Change Adapter Settings > Advanced > Advanced Settings.

I think if you change the priority in the top box you'll get what you're looking for.

Comment: You may need to hit the `alt` key to get the "Advanced" menu to show up. Also if their mobile provider requires you to activate the connection (Similar to a PPoE connection) you may need to check a box for "Autodial" or similar.